# IIS 8 HTTPS/Require SSL causes timeout error

Tags: iis, ssl, https, web, timeout

Trying to publish a website via IIS 8 over SSL, but got time out errors. Any help is appreciated.

Steps taken:

1. Verified the website can be visited via HTTP (`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` works - Using IP address at this moment if that matters)
2. IIS > Server certificate > Create self-signed certificate, type = Web Hosting
3. IIS > Default website > Bindings > HTTPS = 443, Host name = `<blank>`, Certificate = `<The one from the previous step>`
4. IIS > SSL settings > Require SSL = Checked, Client certificate = Ignore
5. IIS > Default website > Permissions > Made sure IIS_IUSRS have read/execute/list permissions
6. IIS > Default website > Restart

Result:

- HTTPS requests from clients (`https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`) return error "This webpage is not available"/ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (Chrome) or "This page can’t be displayed" (IE)
- HTTPS requests from the server itself (`https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`) return the same error as above
- HTTPS request using localhost from the sever itself (`https://localhost`) succeeds after accepting warnings about the certificate

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 12):

Check port 443 in your host. This port is closed by default in some hosting providers.
For example, in Amazon EC2 you must change "Security Group" settings to add "HTTPS"

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-ssl-related-issues-server-certificate) and solved my issue :)

Comment: An external link can break without notice, so if possible you should quote the key paragraphs here to make a complete answer.

Comment: @LexLi. Thanks for your suggestion, I will keep it in mind in my next posts. Unfortunately, I wrote my comment almost 3 years ago and now I don't know what is this all about. The good news is that the link still works, so if anyone finds it useful maybe could do it :)