# Microsoft IIS Server & Angular - Adding SSL parameter

Tags: angular, ssl, iis, https

We have a Microsoft IIS Server that runs a .NET App with Angular, but requires https now to make use of browser push notifications. It works on localhost, but not when releasing it for testing.
I have added the appropriate parameter inside the package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve -- --ssl=true",
```

when I run "npm run start" locally, it processes the parameter as expected and serves the page over https.

Any ideas why it doesn't work with the build pipeline? The page is only accessible with normal http and results in a timeout if I try https. Are there any other settings that I forgot to change?

Comment: Some suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942761/iis-8-https-require-ssl-causes-timeout-error

Comment: Based on limited information above, you merely configured `ng serve` to enable HTTPS, but not IIS. However, to make your site on IIS accessible via HTTPS, you have to add a valid HTTPS site binding.

Comment: How did you deploy application on IIS? When you set [binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWfIB.png) of site, did you change it to https and port to 443? Don't forget to select certificate.